# Adding a UILabel to UiTableViewCell - text is being cropped vertically

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Running into a problem when I try and add a UILabel to a custom UITableViewCell.  For some reason the frame's are not being respected at all - when I try and set the label height (through CGRectMake) the text is being cropped vertically.  In other words, only half of the text is being shown.

When I play around with the CGRectMake's frame height it shows some strange behavior - sometimes a lower value will actually make things align properly.

Am I setting the wrong values?  Is the frame the wrong property to be modifying?

Edit for code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
    // Initialization code
    eventName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    //eventName.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    eventName.numberOfLines = 2;
    eventName.minimumFontSize = 8.;
    eventName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    eventName.text = @"Event Name";
    [self.contentView addSubview:eventName];

    eventStartEndDate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    eventStartEndDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    eventStartEndDate.text = @"Event Start and End Dates";
    [self.contentView addSubview:eventStartEndDate];

    description = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 30.0, 300.0, 20.0)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:description];


}
return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

if (!self.editing) {
    eventName.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 300.0, 20.0);
    eventStartEndDate.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 35.0, 300.0, 20.0);;
}

}
```

Comment: is it the UILabel that is clipping, or the UITableViewCell?  That is, is your label at the bottom of the cell and being clipped, or is it fully in the cell yet is being clipped?

Comment: Posting the code made me realize - it's the description that's causing the problem.  I'm adding it over top of my already added date field and so it appears that it's being clipped.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should pay more attention to memory management. You have to call `release` on your `UILabels`.
The reason, why your `UILabels` sometimes seem clipped is, because your other labels do have a white, opaque background. Setting the `backgroundColor` property to `[UIColor clearColor]` does the trick.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        eventName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        //eventName.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        eventName.numberOfLines = 2;
        eventName.minimumFontSize = 8.;
        eventName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        eventName.text = @"Event Name";
        eventName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:eventName];
        [eventName release];

        eventStartEndDate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        eventStartEndDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        eventStartEndDate.text = @"Event Start and End Dates";
        [self.contentView addSubview:eventStartEndDate];
        [eventStartEndDate release];

        description = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 30.0, 300.0, 20.0)];
        description.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:description];
        [description release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this wasn't production code - I was more just hacking around testing stuff out.  Bad habit but it was a side project so what the hey.